# operators in predicate as argument in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, type-conversion, java-8, predicate

I need to use Predicate as argument in lambda expression. I tried an example code but seeing compiler error. 
I see that the compiler is treating the same Predicate differently for different arguments. So Predicate arguments `n -> true and n -> false` works but `n -> n%4 == 0` doesn't work.

**The compiler error is:**

```
The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
```

I fixed it (*see the replacement code below*) but I am asking should I have to fix it and why? I am not sure if I am missing something basic.

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class PredicateAsArgumentInLambdaExpression {

        public static int add(List<Integer> numList, Predicate predicate) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int number : numList) {
                if (predicate.test(number)) {
                    sum += number;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            numList.add(new Integer(10));
            numList.add(new Integer(20));
            numList.add(new Integer(30));       
            numList.add(new Integer(40));       
            numList.add(new Integer(50));

            System.out.println("Add Everything: "+add(numList, n -> true));
            System.out.println("Add Nothing: "+add(numList, n -> false));
//          System.out.println("Add Less Than 25: "+add(numList, n -> n < 25)); Compiler says: The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
            System.out.println("Add Less Than 25: "+add(numList, n -> Integer.valueOf((int)n) < Integer.valueOf("25")));
//          System.out.println("Add 4 Multiples: "+add(numList, n -> n % 4 == 0)); //Compiler says: The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
            System.out.println("Add 4 Multiples: "+add(numList, n -> Integer.valueOf((int)n) % Integer.valueOf("4")==0));
        }
}
```

Commented out code are what's not working and the line immediately below each is the replacement code. The code works as is and as expected but I was expecting that the commented out code should have worked! What's is it that isn't ok with Predicate in java.util.function.Predicate here?. Please provide any link for specification page if you find the answer in.

Comment: What about using `Predicate<Integer>`?

Comment: @mastov That would then not work for the `true`  and `false` evaluations above the error lines.

Comment: @user3320018 What do you mean? `n -> true` and `n -> false` works fine for me with `Predicate<Integer>`.

Comment: @mastov Besides, would be better to limit the types for Predicate?

Comment: @Pshemo no compiler error in case of `n -> true` and `n -> false`

Comment: @user3320018: Just look at kocko's answer, he tells you how to use the `Predicate<Integer>`.

Comment: @user3320018 "*no compiler error in case of `n -> true` and `n -> false`*" do you want to get compiler error for these cases? If yes, why? If not, then what is the problem (it works fine)?

Comment: @Pshemo The question is about why compiler gives error for the evaluation with % and > operators and not in case of true false evaluations.

Comment: @user3320018 Have you heard about [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)?

Comment: @kocko I'll check it out.

Comment: All - why is there a down vote for my question?

Comment: "why is there a down vote for my question" I am guessing that someone didn't like the fact that your problem is caused by raw types, which are explained in every tutorial about generics.

Comment: @Pshemo I hope you agree that everybody can miss a thing or tow. I did enough research before posting it here. I also hope that I do not need to be PERFECT before I ask a question here. I agree they are explained but please you also agree that anybody can easily miss a thing or two!

Comment: Perfect? No. But you need to understand that some people don't like to spend their time helping someone who they suspect didn't even try to solve problem and they tend to down-vote such posts. That is why it is better to include in question some kind of research effort proof like "I suspect that it may be related to [something] so I tried [someSolution] but it didn't help".

Comment: @Pshemo good point. Please see that I did try and one of the solutions worked and I have mentioned about that. I included only one of my trials fro brevity.

Comment: I never said you didn't. Anyway try not to take down-votes personally. They are subjective matter and there will always be people which wouldn't like something.

Comment: All - the answers look very useful but I am still skeptic about using type-parameter of Integer. I am testing with evaluations involving `double`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that you're using a *raw* [`java.util.function.Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), on which the `test()` method would look like:

```
public void test(Object o) { ... }
```

This is why you get a compile-time error: the argument type is `Object` and the numeric operators (`<`, `>`) are not applicable for the type `Object`.

However, if you use a generic [`java.util.function.Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) with type-parameter of `Integer`, the `test()` method would look like:

```
public void test(Integer i) { ... }
```

In this case, the numeric operators (`>`, `<`) are valid for the provided argument type (`Integer`) and there's no need of casts.

Also, I've taken advantage of the Stream API in Java8 to shorten your method implementation:

```
public static int add(List<Integer> numList, Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
     return numList.stream().filter(predicate).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
}
```

Having the method implemented like this, now all these statements will be perfectly valid:

```
System.out.println("Add Everything: "+add(numList, n -> true));
System.out.println("Add Nothing: "+add(numList, n -> false));
System.out.println("Add Less Than 25: "+add(numList, n -> n < 25));
System.out.println("Add 4 Multiples: "+add(numList, n -> n % 4 == 0));
```

Comment: I replaced my method with your's but seeing compiler error: `The method sum() is undefined for the type 
 Stream<Integer>`

Comment: As an alternative `IntPredicate` can be used which works for primitive `int` type.

Comment: @user3320018, you don't have any stream API in provided code snippet, so it's unlikely that we can help you with this compiler error with this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're overlooking the generic parameter in your `add` method. If you switch from general `Predicate` to `Predicate<Integer>`, then `n` will automatically be cast to an `Integer` before operation.

In short, instead of:

```
public static int add(List<Integer> numList, Predicate predicate) {
```

you should try:

```
public static int add(List<Integer> numList, Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
```

Afterwards, your previous code of:

```
n -> Integer.valueOf((int)n) < Integer.valueOf("25")
n -> Integer.valueOf((int)n) % Integer.valueOf("4")==0
```

can simply be

```
n -> n < 25
n -> n % 4 == 0
```

which is additionally much more efficient.

It's just a question of matching what the method is expecting to what you are providing. As without the generic term, Java expects `Predicate` to receive type `Object` by default, and since `Integer` extends `Object`, it presumes that that is the type you are passing. With it, it expects `Integer`, and all of the methods and operators associated with `Integer` are exposed.

This is a somewhat invisible operation that occurs before your method is called, which is why your warning is on the lambda operation instead of in the method.

Good luck!

Comment: would it work if I used the `<` operator and gave a `double` to compare against. Or any other type for that matter. Predicate<Integer> seems limiting doesn't it?

Comment: It will absolutely work. Look up "autoboxing". `Double` and `Integer` both extend `Number`, so you're covered; additionally, you can't define a generic to be a primitive type like `int`, as those are entirely their own species of class in Java. So you won't be limited at all.